# Ubuntu Creating Files/Folders in Network Share Are Locked

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, network-shares

I have two machines, both Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. One of them has a shared folder "/domains" (shared by right clicking and choosing "Local Network Share"), and the other Ubuntu machine has that folder mounted.

[image]

My problem is that when I create a folder or a file from the client server, the folder/file is locked and I cannot modify anything about it until I change the permissions of it manually on the server side. How do I make these files default to not be locked?

Comment: Note that a file being "locked" is entirely differant than a file with incorrect permissions, denying access. I don't use samba Usershares, and instead 0set the smb.conf `Create Mode =2740` so that the file comes out with the same owner-group of the parent directory and 740 permissions on the file. use `ls -al /share/root/directory/` to determine if your issue is permissions or ownership.

Comment: It was permissions, and your comment was all I needed to solve this problem. If you post an answer like your comment I'd be more than happy to mark it as the correct answer. And by the way, I'm using samba purely because it makes things easy with Windows, which is a factor in my case